# Relu not works, sigmoid works fine

Tags: deep-learning, mobilenet

I am confused with one phenomenon when I use sigmoid in output layer，the network works fine. But the network does not converge if I set the activation of output as Relu.the training loss would not reduce, after the first epoch. Could anybody explain this phenomenon.

The input of network is image. the pixel is rescaled into 0-1. the output is one value varing from 0-1.

thanks.

Comment: What loss function are you using?

Comment: both relu and sigmoid are tested. I detailed describe my question in this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59656204/resnet50-does-not-converge-vgg16-works-fine, could you please give me some advice. Thanks a lot.

Comment: relu and sig;oid are activation functions, not loss function, a loss function would be something like 'cross-entropy' or 'mse'. In fact using relu as an activation in the last layer hasn't a lot of sense, because in general you have one of tree cases: Regression, Binary classification or multi-class classification , in the first it is better to use no activation and use mse as loss, in the second it is best to use sigmoid with binary-crossentorpy and in the last it is better to softmax with variational cross-entropy.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar question and had it solved now. The Neural network had just 3 layers to train MNIST data. Sigmoid activation worked but relu did not, everything else being the same. I reduced the **learning rate** from 3 to 0.1, Relu worked then.
I got the idea from here: [NN not converge with Relu](https://ai.stackexchange.com/questions/15396/network-doesnt-converge-with-relu-or-leaky-relu-but-works-well-with-sigmoid-ta/15400#15400?newreg=f98bda1dc1a74a55aa0e44357f137385)

Answer (score 0):

From what I understand from your question above is, when you use `ReLu` as your final activation the model doesn't converge :

If that's the case then the answer is in the`ReLu` function itself, what `ReLu` does is it doesn't scale the network output between `[0,1]` but instead returns `max(0, x)` which you don't want as your `output/ground truth` is scaled between [0, 1] and `sigmoid` does scale the network output between `[0, 1]` which is as per your ground-truth.

To understand better, consider you what the final layer of your network to return probability between `[0, 1]` which is achieved by using `sigmoid` but cant be achieved by `ReLu` due to the function definition.

So to compute loss your `ground-truth` and your `network output` should be in the same range which is achieved by sigmoid and hence model converges for `sigmoid` in your case.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I had one other question.

Comment: I trained one regress network, using resnet50 as backbone. the input of network is image (224*224*3, pixel rescaled into 0-1), the output is one value(0-1). the network doesn't converge no matter I use relu or sigmoid as activation function of output. But when I use VGG16 as backbone, sigmoid as output's activation function, the network converges. Could you give me some suggestions.

Comment: 1 - Check from where the loss starts for both the model and for VGG16 check where does it reach

2 - Check the model behavior when you provide a higher learning rate, in your case try using a high LR (possibly 1e-2) for resnet50 and check if there is any change in loss, one reason for loss not improving might be that it might have stuck at a possible plateau.