# Resnet50 does not converge. VGG16 works fine

Tags: deep-learning, resnet, vgg-net

I trained one **regression** network using **resnet50** as backbone. The **input** of the network is image whose size is **224*224*3**, the **output** of the network is **one value**, varying from **0** to **1**.

but the netwrok can not converge, no matter I use **sigmoid** or **relu** as output layer's activation. **mae** or **mse** as **loss function**.

For exampple, I use **resnet50** as backbone,**mae** as loss function, **sigmoid** is the activation function of output layer. **SGD** as optimizer. The training loss would be:

`Epoch 1 training loss is 0.4900， val_loss is 0.4797`

`Epoch 2 training loss is 0.4923, val_loss is 0.4794`

`Epoch 3 training loss is 0.4923, val_loss is 0.4783`

`...`

`Epoch 35 training loss is 0.4923, val_loss is 0.4771`

The training loss would not change, it is constant 0.4923. the val_loss is always about 0.47. I tested different**optimizer**, **learning rate**. the network is still not converge.

When I use **VGG16** or **Mobilenet** as backbone, the network converged. 
Could anyone give me some suggestions about how I can fix this problem.

Comment: Change the loss function first to binary cross entropy instead of mae. I imagine that your outputs are probabilities, can you tell us if possible what do they represent in reality. I iamgine that they are probabilites of present of an event in an image.

Answer (score 0):

Can you somehow validate if the Resnet50 backbone is correctly implemented. Maybe try to train it on MNIST and see if it works in general.

It kinda seems to me that the ResNet varaint just outputs some mean value instead of learning the actual problem.

Can you give some more information on what you want to achieve. How your regression looks like and what input is expected from the backbone. Also you might want to have a look at similar work (if that exists) and read what architectures they were using and what hyperparameters.

Comment: the resnet50 is predefiend in keras. so I think it is correctly implemented.

Comment: I input one image, the output of the network are coordinates of one point. e.g. the coordinat x,and y. both x and y are rescaled into 0-1. for example, input  img1.jpg the output would be point1(coor_x,coor_y). actually, the output has two neurons.

Comment: @shc are you sure that you managed to complete this task my using VGG16 and MobileNet, normally they shouldn't give you good results if you use them for this task

Comment: I did something very similar some time ago.I used some VGG inspired architecture. I remember I tried out some optimizers with different LR, different loss functions and activations. The only setup which did work for me in the end was SGD optimizer, MSE loss, relu activations for all layers except the last which had sigmoid. What you can also try is to use a small subset (10 images or something) for training and see if the network is able to overfit, to get some check if the network is even able to learn and try out things form there.

Comment: @othmanmarfoq yes the resnet50 works when I set the activation fucntion of output as 'linear'. Thanks